# I don't know how to get Py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm on Mac OSX 10.10.2. I've tried this once before and got a lot of hate for not being as smart as people assumed I was. I'll say this right now: I don't know anything about Terminal.

I do not have working pip, and I tried following [these instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) to install pip, but even though I have get-pip.py sitting right on my desktop, whenever I execute the command it tells me to in terminal, I get an error: "No such file or directory."  Can someone walk me through the steps of getting Py2app, and pip if that's necessary? I apologize in advance for my stupidity, and thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't Install Py2app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424740/i-cant-install-py2app)

Comment: @Odedra that didn't work.  I'm trying again.

Comment: Yes at your side doesn't work but you may not ask same question as already in SO. If you have different question than you may ask. Otherwise you should have to wait for your desire answer. Or you may delete your question. Because in SO, not welcome any duplication question. Thanks

Comment: When you execute `python get-pip.py`, make sure you're in the right directory. If your `get-pip.py` is on your Desktop, you have to get there first via `cd ~/Desktop`

Comment: So how exactly do I get there?  When do I type `cd ~/Desktop`?

Comment: @Odedra No, it is allowed to ask a duplicate question only if the original duplicate doesn't answer the OP's question. This question is not a duplicate as the answer in the supposed 'duplicate' doesn't work.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ - it is **not** appropriate to ask a duplicate just because the original does not answer the OP question. The **duplicate** criteria is on the **question** not the answers or lack thereof. Questions are duplicates or they are not duplicates, if they are dupes then they should be down voted and closed as such. You are promoting degenerate behavior!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You are incorrect, it is appropriate ***as long as*** there is something different about the new question *or* the OP clearly explains that they've looked at the duplicate question (in their original text) and that it has not answered their question.

Comment: if it is different how is it a duplicate then, you are **specifically** promoting that it is appropriate to ask **duplicates** just to get different/new answers, that is crap logic.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson No, that's not what I said. I said that it is appropriate to ask a duplicate *if* the 'duplicate' does not answer the OP's question ***and*** the OP specifies that they have already tried the solution mentioned in the duplicate and that it didn't work because of some difference (perhaps the OP has a different OS, or a newer version of a library).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This question is not a duplicate because the 'duplicate' provided by Odedra is closed.

Comment: I would suggest the command line crash course in the Appendix A of Learn Python the hard way. It's a really gentle introduction to the basics of the command line, and it doesn't assume you know anything. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after I downloaded get-pip.py, it wasn't working because **I didn't specify the location.**  Before executing `python get-pip.py`, I had to speficy location.  So, on the first line of Terminal, type `cd ~/Desktop` and press enter.  Then execute `python get-pip.py`, and it should work.  Did for me!